# How do I take a list and parse into a list of objects in a class? (Python)

Tags: python, list, file, class

I have a class with several objects. I am supposed to take a text file, open it and parse it into a list of objects, then return the list of Entry objects

I'm struggling to understand how to convert the list I made from the file, into a list of objects.

```
class Entry:

    def __init__(self, account_num, name, balance, phone, city):
        self.account_num = account_num
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.phone = phone
        self.city = city

def read_file(file_given):
    open_file = open(file_given)
    entry_obj = []
    for line in open_file:
        word = line.split()
        entry_obj.append(word)
    open_file.close()
    return entry_obj
```

the text file I'm reading contains:

```
100  Alan   Jones   348.17  8053564820      SLO
700  Suzy   Green   -14.22  8052586912      SLO
```

Comment: What is the input format of the file?

Comment: Can you include the file content in your post.

Comment: Looks like ```entry_obj.append(word)```  might need to be ```entry_obj.append(Entry(*line.split()))```

Comment: Hi! Its a text file that I am reading

Comment: How does a line look like in this file that you're readying, can you give us an example?

Comment: Do you know how to instantiate an `Entry` object? I recommend going through the python docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects. Once you can instantiate an object, you just need to append the object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this should work:

```
def map_to_entry(line):
    attribute_list = line.split()
    account_num = attribute_list[0]
    name = "{} {}".format(attribute_list[1], attribute_list[2])
    balance = attribute_list[3]
    phone = attribute_list[4]
    city = attribute_list[5]
    
    return Entry(account_num, name, balance, phone, city)

def read_file(file_given):
    open_file = open(file_given)
    entry_obj = []
    for line in open_file:
        entry_obj.append(map_to_entry(line))
    open_file.close()
    return entry_obj
```

Comment: I would hesitate to array the argument list in that fashion, mostly for how readable and recognizable it is, and also to save a headache in the future when some aspect of the arguments changes. (like a column gets deleted, or they get rearranged)

Answer (score 1):

It could be as easy as using

```
objList = [Entry(*li) for li in data]
```

But sadly, for some reason your names are split like this. `Alan   Jones` and it creates a list like

```
[['100', 'Alan', 'Jones', '348.17', '8053564820', 'SLO'], ['700', 'Suzy', 'Green', '-14.22', '8052586912', 'SLO']]
```

therefor we will get the error, `TypeError: __init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 7 were given`.
So we have to join these elements.

```
new = []
for l in read_file():
    l[1:2] = [' '.join(l[1:3])]
    l.pop(2)
    new.append(l)
objList = [Entry(*li) for li in new]
```

objList will look like.

```
[<__main__.Entry object at 0x7fe78db6a970>, <__main__.Entry object at 0x7fe78db6acd0>]
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined your class already, but in order to 'instantiate' (create an instance of) class objects, now you must call the class. (seen in example below as `Entry()`, where the `()` lets us know that we are calling / invoking the thing)

You definitely want to keep your arguments spelled out in the **init**() method, just as you have them. It's good to keep things concise and human-readable.
*edit - i changed the name args to be _first, and _last, separately. Reason below.

Note that in the below example, the loop variable **line** is a complete, single set of Entry data. Ergo, by using an asterisk before it, Python will look for a list (or really, any iterable) and it will automatically send each list element to the function call as its own arg.

e.g.  if **line** == 'a b c', then `Entry(*line.split())` is equivalent to  `Entry('a', 'b', 'c')`

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, account_num, name_first, name_last, balance, phone, city):
        self.account_num = account_num
        self.name = name_first + ' ' + name_last
        self.balance = balance
        self.phone = phone
        self.city = city

def read_file(file_given):
    open_file = open(file_given)
    lines = open_file.readlines()
    entry_obj = []
    for line in lines:
        entry_obj.append(Entry(*line.split()))
    open_file.close()
    return entry_obj
```

**edit - this, of course, assumes that we know the order of the data columns as they are received. there are much more robust ways of making this code future-proof, but I digress.

Comment: This probably won't work for how the name is formatted into both first name and last name right?

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack all the elements during an iteration. If your names are always assumed to be First Name and Last Name, you can concatenate them before creating the Entry object. The following example is quite readable:

```
entries = []
for account_num, first_name, last_name, balance, phone, city in read_file('data.txt'):
  name = first_name + " " + last_name
  entries.append(Entry(account_num, name, balance, phone, city))
```

Also one-liner if you're into that:

```
entries = [Entry(account_num, first_name + " " + last_name, balance, phone, city) for account_num, first_name, last_name, balance, phone, city in read_file('ok.txt')]
```

Unpacking in python means to take an iterable with a size you know before-hand and unpack every single element into different variables. Something like:

```
a, b, c = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

The same idea can be applied to elements in a for loop, on which element is another iterable (of a fixed size) itself, as is the case of each row in your file. This allows you to convert a list into named variables, which are usually easier to read.

If your original question was to modify the `read_file` function, you can use a similar idea and unpack while iterating the file:

```
def read_file(file_given):
    open_file = open(file_given)
    entry_obj = []
    for line in open_file:
        account_num, first_name, last_name, balance, phone, city = line.split()
        name = first_name + " " + last_name
        entry_obj.append(Entry(account_num, name, balance, phone, city))
    open_file.close()
    return entry_obj
```